# Spring cloud Data Flow Task sample python task not working

Tags: python, spring, cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am trying to do the sample python task:

Install local with docker:
https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/

Then proceed to create python task:
https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/polyglot/task/

(To add application/launch task to SCDF I use web UI)
Then I obtain on the SCDF console the stacktrace below:

Thanks in advace.

```
Dataflow-server      | java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception trying to launch [AppDeploymentRequest@67fda9c3 commandlineArguments = list['--spring.cloud.task.executionid=10'], deploymentProperties = map[[empty]], definition = [AppDefinition@2680ec0a name = 'aaaaaa', properties = map['management.metrics.tags.service' -> 'task-application', 'spring.cloud.task.closecontextenabled' -> 'true', 'spring.datasource.username' -> 'root', 'spring.datasource.url' -> 'jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow', 'spring.datasource.driverClassName' -> 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver', 'management.metrics.tags.application' -> '${spring.cloud.task.name:unknown}-${spring.cloud.task.executionid:unknown}', 'spring.cloud.task.name' -> 'aaaaaa', 'spring.datasource.password' -> 'rootpw']], resource = Docker Resource [docker:gmolteni2/python-task-with-status:0.1]]
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher.launch(LocalTaskLauncher.java:126)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService.executeTask(DefaultTaskExecutionService.java:402)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$422cda43.invoke(<generated>)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$adb8062d.executeTask(<generated>)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.TaskExecutionController.launch(TaskExecutionController.java:193)
dataflow-server      |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
dataflow-server      |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
dataflow-server      |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
dataflow-server      |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
dataflow-server      |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
dataflow-server      |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
dataflow-server      |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
dataflow-server      |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
dataflow-server      | Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/tmp/2915681239646/aaaaaa-29aa4e7f-ab11-41ec-a9dd-92bbd70813dc"): error=2, No such file or directory
dataflow-server      |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
dataflow-server      |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher$TaskInstance.start(LocalTaskLauncher.java:350)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher$TaskInstance.access$200(LocalTaskLauncher.java:254)
dataflow-server      |  at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher.launch(LocalTaskLauncher.java:119)
dataflow-server      |  ... 71 common frames omitted
dataflow-server      | Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
dataflow-server      |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
dataflow-server      |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
dataflow-server      |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
dataflow-server      |  ... 76 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Cloud Local Deployer starts docker containers by building a shell command for the Docker CLI and executing it with a system call.

Your stacktrace contains the message

> Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/tmp/2915681239646/aaaaaa-29aa4e7f-ab11-41ec-a9dd-92bbd70813dc"): error=2, No such file or directory

You need to run Dataflow as a user that has access to the shell command `docker`. If you run Dataflow itself as a Docker container, you need to install Docker in that container and mount the Docker socket of the host machine into the container.

Comment: I was running into the same message on my local. If anybody else is interested, the documentation can be found at https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/#docker-stream--task-applications, where it is explained how to use `docker-compose` approach and how to use such setup like they have linked in their [docker-compose-dood.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/main/src/docker-compose/docker-compose-dood.yml).